# Discord.py(v 1.5.0) : TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, discord, discord.py

So im trying to make a discord bot, and I want to make a command that sends a message to all channels.

```
    @client.command(pass_context = True)
async def send_all(ctx):
    channel = client.get_all_channels()
    await channel.send("I sent this to all channels")
```

At first(When I make the bot online), there are no errors. But when I run the command, no output comes out in discord and in the console, this comes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
for channel in client.get_all_channels():
    # get_all_channels also include voice channels, just check if it's not
    if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel):
        await channel.send('whatever')
```

You can also:

```py
for guild in client.guilds:
    for channel in guild.text_channels:
        await channel.send('whatever')
```

`Bot.get_all_channels` yields a `GuildChannel` obj - means it's an iterator, to learn more about iterators check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration)

#### Reference:

- [`Bot.get_all_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_all_channels)
- [`Bot.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.guilds)
- [`Guild.text_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.text_channels)